# 特定要素が存在する配列のみ別の配列に追加する

Tags: google-apps-script

この場合、rowsに対して期待された結果[[right, black], [right, red]]が得られていないようです。誰か問題点を指摘できますか ?

```
const values = [[,,],[,'right','black'],[,'right','red'], [,'left','black'],[,'left', 'black']];
const cols=[];
const rows=[];
for(let row=1;row<5;row=row+1){
  if(values[row][1]=='right'){
    cols.splice(0);
    for(let i=1;i<3;i=i+1){cols.push(values[row][i]);}
    rows.push(cols);
  }
}
Logger.log(rows)// [[right, red], [right, red]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 問題点

`rows` に constで宣言した配列`cols`をpushしているのがミステイクです。
配列Aに配列Bをpushする場合、実際に配列Aにpushされるデータは配列Bの参照です。
なので、質問文のコードのrowsに入っているデータは`[cols, cols]`と同義です。
試しに、質問文のコードに続いて以下のコードを実行してみてください。

```js
cols.push('foo');
Logger.log(rows)
```

結果は、`[[right, red, foo], [right, red, foo]]` になるはずです。
このことで、rowsの中に入っているのはcolsの参照でしかないことが分かります。

この現象を回避するには、rowsにpushする配列colsをif文のスコープ中で毎回新しく作成すれば良いです。

```js
const values = [[,,],[,'right','black'],[,'right','red'], [,'left','black'],[,'left', 'black']];
// const cols は不要。
const rows=[];
for(let row=1;row<5;row=row+1){
  if(values[row][1]=='right'){
    let cols = []; // if内でブロックスコープとしてcolsを定義する。
    for(let i=1;i<3;i=i+1){cols.push(values[row][i]);}
    rows.push(cols);
  }
};
Logger.log(rows) // [ [ 'right', 'black' ], [ 'right', 'red' ] ]
```

Comment: colsの宣言位置を修正する際、宣言をconstからletに変更したことに特別な意図はありますか？その点のみ小さな気がかりが残っています。

Comment: 特別な意図はありません。スコープのライフサイクルも短いのでどちらを使っても構わないでしょう。厳密さを求めるのであればconstであると思いますが私はそこまで思い詰めてコードを書いていません。